# Drawrectangle border missing in GDIPlus

Tags: drawing, gdi+

```
CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

Graphics graphics(dc.m_hDC);
float x = 10
float y= 10
float width = 400;
float height = 400;

RectF rectfloat(x,y,width,height);//rectangle 

RectF clipRect(rectfloat);
graphics.SetClip(clipRect,CombineModeReplace);

graphics.FillRectangle(&SolidBrush(Color(255, 255, 0, 0)), rectfloat);

float lineWidth =1;
Pen pen(Color(255,0,0,0),lineWidth);

graphics.DrawRectangle(&pen,rectfloat);
```

Why the right and bottom lines are missing from `DrawRectangle`?
If I change the `pixeloffsetMode` of graphics to `PixelOffsetModeHalf` the top and bottom line are missing.I don't want to remove the clipping.I want to know why the border is missing if I use the same dimension as clipped graphics.

Comment: remove `graphics.SetClip(clipRect,CombineModeReplace);` and it works

Comment: I don't want to remove the clipping..I want to know why the border is not coming if I set the same dimension for clipping